# Website built with jekyll displays differently from local when push the changes to github

Tags: html, css, github, web, jekyll

I am using a jekyll template to build my website. I made all the changes locally and it runs all smoothly. However, when I push all the changes to github and open the github.io link, the front page is displayed differently. I am wondering what the possible problem is?

The difference is specifically the way that the front page of the website is displayed. Locally, it is supposed to show all the posts with "Page 1 out of 1". But on the github host it does not.

This is the github repository: https://github.com/BiostatisticsPodcast/BiostatisticsPodcast.github.io

Thank you guys in advance!

I tried to edit the config.yml file from scratch and it still does not show. I suspect the problem is in index.html but I cannot figure it out. :(

Answer (score 1):

You publish your page [from a branch](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch). Under the hood, this uses the [jekyll-build-pages action](https://github.com/actions/jekyll-build-pages), with [fixed versions for Jekyll and its dependencies](https://pages.github.com/versions/). On top of that, the number of plugins is limited to a short list, which does *not* include the jekyll-archives plugin your theme requires, as the [corresponding line in the config file](https://github.com/BiostatisticsPodcast/BiostatisticsPodcast.github.io/blob/5424696e0cf107a5f53f5a0f7c8cec7b246fccce/_config.yml#L4) indicates:

```yaml
  - jekyll-archives # Sorry, not GitHub pages friendly!
```

The solution is to switch to [publishing with a GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow). You can use the [Jekyll starter workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/jekyll.yml); follow the instructions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-starter-workflows#using-starter-workflows) to set it up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. and Im sure this should be the fix. However, when I try to use the Jekyll started workflow you linked, I got this error: Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for 'pages' exists.

I am wondering what that means. Sorry I am not very familiar with this process and thanks again.

Comment: @Choochoojc It looks like you copy-pasted the workflow instead of selecting it from the starter workflows, resulting in the default branch not being set properly [here](https://github.com/BiostatisticsPodcast/BiostatisticsPodcast.github.io/blob/bf3cc7cdedb59406f37d4968018d85581fad59cd/.github/workflows/main.yml#L12); you have to replace `[$default-branch]` with `[main]`. Also, make sure you have selected "GitHub Actions" in the "Source" settings at https://github.com/BiostatisticsPodcast/BiostatisticsPodcast.github.io/settings/pages.